# Performance of the Application with a database

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, cloud

If you have any problem with the comment, download an application with java and netbeans using a mysql database, there are 2 options:

1.When I work with the java application consuming my database from my own machine, it goes smoothly in that way:
does not slow down when showing the data from the database among other points, such as when showing a list of products in a table

2.when I work with the java application consuming an external database such as hostinger, which is in my case, it goes slow in such cases, an example: when opening a table with a list of products it takes almost 2 minutes to display and it should not be so really

Well based on all this I have used pool connections both with the classes: ComboPooledDataSource and BasicDataSource but anyway it is still the same or capable I am missing some value to add, I cannot find the solution to this problem, 2 words come to mind which are connections or network latency, I would really appreciate if you would support me with this ..

Comment: Yep it's the network latency. No matter how fast your network connection is, the data transfer is still happening between your local system and the database server. When your application is deployed on a server then the things are different because at both ends there are big servers and super high speed internet and also many mechanisms to speed up the data transfer.

Comment: If you want to optimize your local system for data fetching from server I would suggest you to add a caching mechanism such as redis or memcache to cache your db calls

Comment: Hello, thanks for the support, you told me about the implementation of the cache mechanism, but if something could be done both in software or in the server or is it required to use these mechanisms anyway?

Comment: Servers usually have it sorted. Better servers have better service and gives performance but then you will have to pay them accordingly. So the best option we have is to do it on our software end. There are many mechanisms and system designs to improve the performance of the application. The entire dev ops is all about it. You need to study about servers and system design principles for more detailed information.

Comment: It can be done at everywhere. Your code, your server, your application, your database, your table structure, etc in every possible place you can think of. Its like our human body. You can improve your physical strength, your mental strength, your looks, your clothes, your fame, and what not. It'll all improve you. Same goes for application. Every component and aspect have a room for improvement.

Comment: Additional information request from your hostinger instance and OS, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.